# Qt: QDesktopWidget file not found

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm trying to use the QDesktopWidget class, just to resize a window. It appears to be the main class to get the geometry of a user's screen, but Qt cannot find it.

I tried adding `QT += widgets` in my .pro file, followed by running qmake, but unfortunately this did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/widgets-changes-qt6.html) (emphasis mine):

> **QDesktopWidget was already deprecated in Qt 5, and has been removed in Qt 6**, together with QApplication::desktop().
>
> **QScreen provides equivalent functionality** to query for information about available screens, screen that form a virtual desktop, and screen geometries.